# Why is my controller return wrong response data?

Tags: asp.net-core

I`m using Ajax call to remove items from list. When user clicks on remove button (each button for row with id) it sends Ajax call (Post) to Order/RemoveFromCart. When backend is reached i remove the item from list. Im sure when returning data from controller the item i want to remove is truly removed. The problem is when i take my div and call html(data) from response it removes always the last item in the list.

Thank you for help.

I have tried update dotnet to latest version. 
I have tried to remove Ajax call and reload whole view - that fixes the problem but i want to use an Ajax call.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CartItems.Count; i++)
{
   <input asp-for="CartItems[i].ProductId" type="hidden">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <input type="text" class="inputTextWithoutBorder" readonly="readonly" asp-for="CartItems[i].Product">
       </td>
       <td>
           <select class="select-table" asp-for="@Model.CartItems[i].Packaging" asp-items="@Model.CartItems[i].PackageTypes"></select>
       </td>
       <td>
           <input type="text" class="inputTextWithoutBorder" asp-for="@Model.CartItems[i].Amount" placeholder="Vyberte množství...">
       </td>
       <td>
           <button id="removeFromCartId" onclick="removeFromCart(this);" type="button" value="@i" class="removeButton"></button>
       </td>
   </tr>
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RemoveFromCart(OrderModel model, int itemToRemove)
{
    if (model.CartItems[itemToRemove] != null)
    {
         model.CartItems.RemoveAt(itemToRemove);
    }
    return PartialView("_OrderCartWithCalendarPartial", model);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class CartModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }     
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Packaging { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PackageTypes { get; } = 
    new List<SelectListItem>{
        new SelectListItem {Value = "", Text = ""},
        };
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function removeFromCart(button) {
    var index = button.value;
    var placeholderElement = $('#orderFormId');
    var myformdata = placeholderElement.serialize() 
    + "&itemToRemove=" + index;
    var result = $.post("/Order/RemoveFromCart", myformdata);
    result.done(function (data) {
        $("#cartWithCalendarDiv").html(data);
        setDateFieldToZero();
    }); 
}
```

Problem scenario:
Sending via Ajax list with two items (item0, item1). The controller receives exact list with two items. Remove item0 in controller and return partial view with that updated model. The page reloads only with item0. Why?